# I can't get second class in C++ Code::Blocks to work

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I just started learning C++ and currently I'm trying to create new namespaces in 2 different classes.

But I can't seem to add second class to my project in CodeBlocks, even though I think I included everything properly, it just looks like compiler ignores the second class and cant import the namespace I created.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Pokemon.h"
#include "animals.h"

using namespace std;

using namespace pokemons;

int main()
{

Pokemon pikachu("Pikachu", 1);

pikachu.pokeAttack();




return 0;
}
```

Source file:

```
#include "animals.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace pokemons{

Pokemon::Pokemon()
{
cout << "I choose you, " << name << endl;
}

Pokemon::~Pokemon()
{
cout << "Come back to Pokeball, " << name << endl;
}

Pokemon::Pokemon(string name, int type){
        this->name = name;
        this->type = type;

        cout << "I choose you, " << name << "!!!" << endl;
    }

void Pokemon::pokeAttack(){
if (type = 1){

    cout << name << " used tackle" << endl;
}
}

}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef POKEMON_H
#define POKEMON_H

#include <string>

namespace pokemons{


class Pokemon
{
public:
    Pokemon();
    virtual ~Pokemon();
    void pokeAttack();
    Pokemon(std::string name, int type);
protected:
private:
    std::string name;
    int type;
};

}

#endif // POKEMON_H
```

The first class and namespace works perfectly fine so I'm not including it here. Don't mind the pokemon, I just didn't know what to use for training.
Oh, and here is the error  http://prntscr.com/aw12nj

```
||=== Build: Debug in namespacesTrening (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\PC\Documents\Ceplusplus\namespacesTrening\main.cpp|7|error:    'pokemons' is not a namespace-name|
C:\Users\PC\Documents\Ceplusplus\namespacesTrening\main.cpp|7|error:    expected namespace-name before ';' token|
C:\Users\PC\Documents\Ceplusplus\namespacesTrening\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\PC\Documents\Ceplusplus\namespacesTrening\main.cpp|12|error: 'Pokemon' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\PC\Documents\Ceplusplus\namespacesTrening\main.cpp|12|note:      suggested alternative:|
include\Pokemon.h|9|note:   'poki2::Pokemon'|
C:\Users\PC\Documents\Ceplusplus\namespacesTrening\main.cpp|12|error: expected ';' before 'pikachu'|
C:\Users\PC\Documents\Ceplusplus\namespacesTrening\main.cpp|14|error: 'pikachu' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Adding the first class:
source file Pokemon.cpp

```
#include "Pokemon.h"
#include <iostream>



namespace poki2{

Pokemon::Pokemon()
{
    cout << "I choose you, " << name << endl;
}

Pokemon::~Pokemon()
{
    cout << "Come back to Pokeball, " << name << endl;
}

Pokemon::Pokemon(string name, int type){
            this->name = name;
            this->type = type;

            cout << "I choose you, " << name << "!!!" << endl;
        }



void Pokemon::pokeAttack(){
    if (type = 1){

        cout << name << " used thunderbolt!!!" << endl;
    }
}


}
```

The header file Pokemon.h

```
#ifndef POKEMON_H
#define POKEMON_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace poki2 {

class Pokemon
{
    public:
        Pokemon();
        virtual ~Pokemon();
        Pokemon(string name, int type);
        void pokeAttack();

    protected:
    private:
        string name;
        int type;
};

}



#endif // POKEMON_H
```

Comment: Please paste the error text here directly. Having it on a separate site is fragile.

Comment: You probably need to `#include "Pokemon.h"` in the implementation file, `pokemon.cpp`.

Comment: They are included and working, if I understood you correctly

Comment: In your Source File (second code-block) code, that header file doesn't seem to be included

Comment: It's the header for the first class created in Pokemon.cpp and I included it there. But I also included it to the second source file but it doesnt seem to change anything. It seems to be the problem with CodeBlocks not accepting the fact that I created a second source and header file.

Comment: So the third code-block - is that `animals.h` or `Pokemon.h`?

Comment: Also, I don't use CodeBlocks so I'm not sure, but you may need to specify where to find header files that you add in the project settings.

Comment: `if (type = 1)` Whoops.

Comment: _"The first class and namespace works perfectly fine so im not including it here"_ You're not qualified to know that. We require a [MCVE] for these sorts of questions, please.

Comment: The third block is animals.h. I will try setting the search path for the header files, but I dont know if the IDE should have the problem with that since the source and header files are literally in the same folder as the working source and header file from the 1st class

Comment: Alright, adding the first class in a minute

Comment: Don't just dump more code. Produce a cohesive [MCVE]. Read the page I linked you to before proceeding.

Comment: The error message indicates that file `"Pokemon.h"` does not contain `namespace pokemons`

Answer (score 3):

You have `Pokemon` class in both namespaces, so you need to make it clear for the compiler which namespace you are referring to.

```
pokemons::Pokemon
poki2::Pokemon
```

And you use also the same macro name for both `animals.h` and `Pokemon.h`

```
#ifndef POKEMON_H
#define POKEMON_H
[...]
#endif
```

In this case, the `Pokemon.h` will be included first and the POKEMON_H macro will be defined, so when the `animals.h` is included, everything between `#ifndef POKEMON_H` and `#endif` will be dropped.

```
#include "Pokemon.h"
#include "animals.h"
```

When it comes to you `main.cpp` file, you have included both header files, but you are only using `pokemons` namespace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Pokemon.h"
#include "animals.h"

using namespace std;

using namespace pokemons; // You have selected pokemons namespace.

int main()
{
    Pokemon pikachu("Pikachu", 1);

    pikachu.pokeAttack();

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to use both namespaces, the best way is to spesify it in the declaration of the variable and drop `using namespace`

```
pokemons::Pokemon pikachu("Pikachu", 1); // Instance of Pokemon class in namespace pokemons
poki2::Pokemon pikachu2("Pikachu", 1) // Instance of Pokemons class in namespace poki2
```